# Minimization problem using Lagrange multiplier

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, economics

This is a microeconomics question, however, as it is the calculations that cause problems I hope you can help me anyways.

I have to minimize the following using Lagrange:

$$
\min p_1x_1+p_2x_2
$$
subject to $(x_1^p + x_2^p)^{1/p} \geq U$.This means that I have to find $x_1$ and $x_2$ where $x_1$ and $x_2$ may not depend on each other. Thus let 
$$
L = p_1x_1+p_2x_2 - \lambda \left( \left(x_1^p+x_2^p \right)^{1/p} - U \right)
$$
We get that
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_1} :=  p_1 - \lambda \left( \frac{1}{p} \left(x_1^p + x_2^p \right)^{(1/p)-1} px_1^{p-1} \right) = 0
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_2} :=  p_1 - \lambda \left( \frac{1}{p} \left(x_1^p + x_2^p \right)^{(1/p)-1} px_2^{p-1} \right) = 0
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda} :=  (x_1^p + x_2^p)^{1/p} = U
\end{align}

Dividing the first expression with expression 2 one gets
$$
\frac{p_1}{p_2} = \frac{x_1^{p-1}}{x_2^{p-1}}
$$
Thus
$$
x_1 = \left( \frac{p_1x_2^{p-1}}{p_2} \right)^{1/(p-1)}
$$
and then I have to substitute this expression in the third expression but I simply can't see a way to solve for $x_2$ then. Can you help me?

Comment: It'd be much easier to use $L=p1x_1+p_2x_2+\lambda(U^p-x_1^p-x_2^p)$ so $0=\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_1}=p_2-p\lambda x_2^{p-1}$ and $x_i\propto p_i^{-1/(p-1)}$.

Answer (score 1):

I did not go through your computations. But from
$$
\frac{p_1}{p_2} = \frac{x_1^{p-1}}{x_2^{p-1}}
$$
you can deduce that
$$x_1=\lambda\>p_1^{1/(p-1)},\qquad x_2=\lambda\>p_2^{1/(p-1)}$$
for a certain $\lambda>0$. The condition $\left(x_1^p+x_2^p\right)^{1/p}=U$ then determines $\lambda$:
$$\lambda\left(p_1^{p/(p-1)}+p_2^{p/(p-1)}\right)^{1/p}=U\ .$$